# Is it possible to create a new document automatically in Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a bus booking app.I am using Cloud Firestore for this.I want to store the customer details whoever books a ride on a daily basis.So,is it possible to create documents everyday automatically and keep the details of those customers who book through my app? Any kind of response is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean through `automatically`?

Comment: I mean for every new day , I want the list of my customers with that particular date .I cannot manually create a new document daily (which is a waste of time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a new document automatically in Cloud Firestore?

Yes it is. The simplest way is to use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

> Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests. Your code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment.

Then you can schedule the execution of an HTTPS Cloud Function using a third party cron scheduler such as [cron-job.org](http://www.cron-job.org). That's it!

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: In cron-job.org ,it is asking for a URL. Which URL should I put there?because I am using Firestore and not PHP, I don't know what to do

Comment: Take a look [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/startups-now-cronjob-your-google-firebase-functions-securely-and-externally-without-paying-for-503b0f4ca539).

Comment: Can't we use timestamp instead of cloud functions?

Comment: @RohithReddySama I'm sorry but I cannot understand you. Cloud Functions is used to write Node.js functions and the timestamp is used to hold the date and time on property of an object in the database. If you think that there is principle that you don't understand, go ahead and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

yes firestore allow automatic adding new file to the system just use the .add() function

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("name", "Tokyo");
data.put("country", "Japan");
ApiFuture<DocumentReference> addedDocRef = db.collection("cities").add(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model):

> Collections and documents are created implicitly in Cloud Firestore. Simply assign data to a document within a collection. If either the collection or document does not exist, Cloud Firestore creates it.

So just perform an add() for each time a customer books through your app and the document should get created automatically.